# Question about Schengen visa application

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I hold an Indian passport. I am applying for a Schengen visa for a short trip in Eurpe in September 2018.

My itinerary is Bangalore, India -> Dubai on September 22. Dubai -> Sofia, Bulgaria on September 25. Sofia -> Brussels on September 27. Brussels -> Amsterdam on September 28. Amsterdam -> Brussels on October 1. Brussels -> Sofia -> Dubai on October 2. And Dubai -> Bangalore on October 3.

While applying for the visa there is this question: "Is your final destination inside the Schengen Area?"

As per my itinerary, I will be going to Sofia the second time on October 2 using my Schengen visa. What should be the answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your final destination is inside the Schengen area. That question is asking in an indirect fashion whether you will be transiting in the Schengen area, for instance, while on your way to the UK or Canada.